# The best way to call programs from cx_freeze

Tags: python, python-3.x, cx-freeze

I have an ad hoc solution for a group of my scripts (a Tkinter main menu calling programs with something like this):

```
def record_data():
    os.system('python record_data.py')
```

And it works while I don't make any attempts to freeze the program. Clicking a button with a function attached to it doesn`t work after freezing. What is the best way to call a program even after cx_freezing?